# Mysql Fetching data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table: `tbl_offer` (offer_name, location). For a particular offer I have more than one location in location column, separated by commas.

**Example:**

If offer is `offer1` then I have `Bangalore, Mumbai, Chennai` in the location column.

Now want to write a query which will fetch each location separately (which are separated by commas for a particular offer). I want choose the `offer1` it should fetch `Bangalore Mumbai and Chennai` in separate records.

Comment: If you're still developing this app, change it *now* so that you're not storing comma-separated lists in a field.  Otherwise [search here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+split+column) for the thousands of results about the same thing.

Comment: Ya..I got the Idea..Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Cylindric told you, if you can change database design!
Create two tables, one for offers and one for location.

```
OFFERS    (id, name)
LOCATIONS (offer_id, name)
```

So (for example) you have `(1, 'offer1')` in OFFERS and
`(1, 'Bangalore'), (1, 'Mumbai') and (1, 'Chennai')` in LOCATIONS.

Your query will be easier:

```
SELECT o.name, l.name FROM offers o
INNER JOIN locations l ON o.id = l.offer_id
```

---

To be honest, you should have three tables to avoid locations repetitions:

```
OFFERS     (id, name)
LOCATIONS  (id, name)
OFFERS_LOC (offer_id, loc_id)
```

You have
`(1, 'offer1')` in OFFERS,
`(1, 'Bangalore'), (2, 'Mumbai') and (3, 'Chennai')` in LOCATIONS and
`(1, 1), (1, 2) and (1, 3)` in OFFERS_LOC.

Your query will be

```
SELECT o.name, l.name FROM offers o
INNER JOIN offers_loc ol ON o.id = ol.offer_id
INNER JOIN locations l ON ol.loc_id = l.id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mcrco, for your suggestion.